# How can i make realistic lighting for a 3D car?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, light, lighting, volumetrics

I'm making a 3D scene with a car, on Blender Cycles. (fisheye camera)

[image]

Everything does seems fine for me but only the car lights doesnt work because i don't know how to apply them, i already tried to put an 'emission' material on the lights but they just appear as 'shadeless textures'.

I feel like a starter on Cycles when adding lights, but this time i want the actual objects produce the light like a real car would do:

[image]

I can separate the light object part from the rest of the model, so i can add it a material that can emit and generate some light inside of it, i think, right now the headlights have a glossy material.

How can i setup them?

Thanks in regards.

Comment: Lights alone will only go so far. Either you need some volumes to get volumetric light effects and god rays, or composite some glows and lens flares in post production

Comment: You'll probably want to use a glare node.